# Does calling curried function in render have negative performance impact?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I've read that it's good practice to declare function as component's method instead of inlining it in `render`, because every time parent component is rendered it creates new function and messes up with child's `shouldComponentUpdate`.

I.e. this:
`<button onClick={this.handleClick} />`
is better than that: `<button onClick={e => someAction(e)} />`

But what about curried functions? Is the following considered as creating new function?

```
class Parent extends Component {
  handleClick = data => event => someAction(data);

  render() {
    const data = 123;
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick(data)} />;
  }
}
```

I know that the "performance impact" may be unnoticable there, but I find partially applicating function paramaters while passing down the component tree very convienent and I'm wondering if it's against best practices.

Comment: Yes, that’s creating a new function.

Comment: Why do you initialise your `handleClick` in the constructor? It should be a normal method.

Comment: The `data` in your example is constant, which would make inlining it into `handleClick` trivial. What's your actual use case?

Comment: I should recommend this article about inline functions and performance
https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578

Comment: seems fine to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it has negative performance impact because of the extra function invocation. But do you really have to worry about it? Most likely not. There are popular React patterns that use closures in `render`, like https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html Measure first to avoid spending energy on imaginary performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Every time you execute `handleClick` you will get in return a new function. In other words purpose of `handleClick` is to return a new function. If you remove some of the implicit syntaxes you will get:

```
handleClick = data => {
  const innerFunction = event => someAction(data);
  return innerFunction;
}
```

Side note: I've read some benchmarks that such performance impact by creating functions in render may have less impact than most people think.